# Why does Replace(x,Chr(160)) replaces Empty Space AND comma instead of only Empty Space

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to delete some spaces on my whole Sheet. The code below works but is also taking off the Comma from some numbers making the numbers wrong.

```
Sub Deletespaces()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, Chr(160), "")

Next

End Sub
```

[image]     = = = = > 
[image]

Somehow for every number above 1.00, the code is taking the `,` out.
How should I correct my code to keep the comma

Comment: What format are the numbers in?

Comment: Yes, formatting might be the issue. On my side (UK settings) comma is a "thousands separator", meaning that 1,652 is treated as a valid number (one thousand and 652), while 0.903 is treated as General (meaning it isn't recognised by Excel as a number, that is why your code is skipping these cells). I'd also suggest to modify your code a little bit and not loop through all cells in column BI (it makes the whole process very slow).

Comment: In doing a little testing, Excel will recognize numbers if you use `.NumberFormat = "# ###.##0"`, where the gap is the thousands place (comma in US, dot in EU); I have not been able to do the same with a decimal (using NumberFormat).  If you use `.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=" "` (for US equivalent), you will end up with a string, not a number.  Inferring from the above two points, that I cannot get the number format to allow skipping the decimal nor does replacing the decimal allow the value to stay a number, I would say that you cannot get both criteria met without reading from VBA (UDF)

Comment: Have you tried `=VALUE()` and then pasting the values back?  It might work as I think it looks at the language of the workbook.

Comment: Are you sure that you have any non-breakable space (Chr(160)) in the original cells?

Comment: @z32a7ul in some cells below yes I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a sec... I think I confused what the issue is with my first comment...

You want decimal places to have no decimal places and no space between them?

```
For i = top to bottom 'define these
    Cell(i,"BI").value = Cell(i,"BI").value*1000 
Next i
Columns("BI").Numberformat = "###0"
```

Just multiply by 1k, since you have 3 decimal places.

---

Adding a non-loop alternative for the multiply by 1k:

```
dim rng as range
set rng = range(cells(top,"BI"),cells(bottom,"BI")) 'define top and bottom
rng = Evaluate(rng.address & "*1000")
rng.Numberformat = "###0"
```

---

If I am understanding correctly, you would be going from:

```
Old    |    New
1.652  |    1652
0.903  |    903
0.816  |    816
```

If you want that leading 0, you can format with `rng.Numberformat = "0000"`and it looks like:

```
Old    |    New
1.652  |    1652
0.903  |    0903
0.816  |    0816
```

Comment: No I actually wanted to end with 1.652 but my code changes the values to 1652
Except for prices below 1 in which case 0.903 doesn't change

Comment: @Pierre44 so you're just looking to change `Columns("BI").NumberFormat = "#.##0"` rather than "#,##0"?  Might even be affected by `DecimalSeparator` which is under `Application` (i'm not positive how that works, considering the decomal place is a regional system setting)

Comment: No it s rather that Excel couldn't recognize the values in the cells. In Excel you just need to click on the cell and press enter. But a

Comment: @Pierre44 So if I'm understanding correctly, your issue isn't particularly your code but getting Excel to recognize numbers at all?  `Columns("BI").TextToColumns` would resolve that issue.  I apologize if I'm not getting the gist of your issue; i am trying to pair what you are saying in these comments with your post, which doesn't clearly state current to desired situation.

Comment: I change the question/the code to make it only about the main topic. The rest is probably just adding confusion

Comment: @Pierre44 Might I request a clear statement about what your current situation is (e.g., I have an array of strings which are not recognized as numbers, such as 1,652) and what your desired output is (e.g., 1.652), and [put that into your Post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57076630/edit)?  I read the update to read "i want to keep the comma" but that still leaves me with questions about your values/strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do this replacing in case of cells that contain numbers because Replace works with Strings and the Cell's Value is formatted according to many rules, which may be different by your location.

So, I think you should do it only for Cells that contain Strings. I added an If for this purpose to your code:

```
Sub Deletespaces()
    Dim cell As Range: For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If VarType(cell.Value) = vbString Then
            cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, Chr(160), "")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: I don't think other value types could contain a non-breakable space.